# Explain ${#arrayname[@]} syntax for array length in bash?

Tags: arrays, bash, syntax

I know that one can get the length of an array in bash by doing `${#arrayname[@]}`.

My question is: is this just something that I have to memorize, or can this syntax be broken down into understandable parts? For instance, what does the `@` symbol mean where one would expect to find the index? Why the `#`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`#` at the beginning of a variable reference means to get the length of the variable's value. For a normal variable this means its length in characters. `#` is the "number" sign, so you can remember this as meaning "the number of things in the variable".

`@` or `*` in an array index means to use the whole array, not a specific element, and instead of returning the number of characters, it returns the number of array elements. `*` is used as a wildcard in many contexts, so this should be easy to remember. Also, `$*` and `$@` are used to mean all the arguments to a shell script, so the parallel with all the array elements should be obvious.

You can't just write `${#arrayname}` because when you use an array variable without a subscript, it's equivalent to element `0` of the array. So `${#arrayname}` is the same as `${#arrayname[0]}`, which is the number of characters in the first element of the array.

Answer (score 8):

You should memorize. :) The `#` usually means *number*. e.g. the

- `$#` - is the number of arguments
- `${#str}` - length of the string `$str`
- `${#arr[@]}"` - length (number of elements) of the array `arr`
- `${#arr}` - the length of the 1st element of the array (like the `str` above)

Unfortunately the `${parameter#word}` or `${parameter##word}` has nothing with *numbers*. (it removes the shortest/longest `word` from the beginning of the `parameter`.

And also, the `# ....` is comment ;)

Answer (score 4):

In general usage of form `${#PARAMETER}` returns the length in *number of characters* and *NOT* bytes of the parameter's value.

```
myString="Hello StackOverflow!"
printf "%s\n" "${#myString}"
20
```

But for arrays, this expansion type has two meanings:

1. For individual elements, it reports the string length of the element
   (as for every "normal" parameter)
2. For the mass subscripts `@` and `*` it
   reports the number of set elements in the array

Consider an example over arrays,

```
myArray=(1 2 3 4 15)
printf "%s\n" "${myArray[@]}"    # <-- Gives me list of elements 
1
2
3
4
15
printf "%s\n" "${#myArray[@]}"   # <-- Gives me number of elements
5
```

It gets interesting now, the length of the last element `2` can be obtained by doing

```
printf "%s\n" "${#myArray[4]}"
2
```

Answer (score 1):

The '@' acts the same way as '*'. Instead of providing a specific index this references the full thing.

The '#' is telling bash you want the length

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/finding-bash-shell-array-length-elements/